# Enable Programatically Back button in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have been meeting this issue now and then, how to make activity show back button an make it return to the parent activity without too much complexity.

Google have extensive documentation, but it is blown for someone who want a simple working approach. So am putting this question and answering it myself as rather documentation for others.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable the "Back" button with

```kotlin
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

2. Override `onSupportNavigateUp` to make it actually go back

```kotlin
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean 
{
    onBackPressed()
    return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

Here is the full code

```
class SomeChildActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_invoice)

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        onBackPressed()
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```